# How to get link immediate to a tab in product in magento 2

Tags: magento2, geturl

I have a Grid View using UI and i want when click edit a record in this grid, it redirect immediate to tab custom option in Product(#product_info_tabs_customer_options).

In Magento 1.x, i create link when pass params as `'params' => array('tab' => 'id_of_tab')` in function getUrl.
In Magento 2, What do i should to pass params in function getUrl ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The url should contain `/active_tab/order_creditmemos/`

where 'order_creditmemos' is the name attribute of the tab

```
<a href="#sales_order_view_tabs_order_creditmemos_content" ... name="order_creditmemos" ...>
```

See /app/code/Magento/Sales/Block/Adminhtml/Order/Creditmemo/View.php

```
/**
 * Retrieve back url
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getBackUrl()
{
    return $this->getUrl(
        'sales/order/view',
        [
            'order_id' => $this->getCreditmemo() ? $this->getCreditmemo()->getOrderId() : null,
            'active_tab' => 'order_creditmemos'
        ]
    );
}
```